# Pushing a file to the browser using php and modx revolution

Tags: php, download, modx-revolution

I'm trying to generate and push a CSV file [report] to the browser, I place this in a snippet:

```
if (file_exists($filename)) {echo 'reading file';
 header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
 header('Content-Type: text/csv');
 header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($filename));
 //header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
 header('Expires: 0');
 header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
 header('Pragma: public');
 header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filename));
 ob_clean();
 flush();
 readfile($filename);
}
```

Snippet:

```
[[!downloadReport? &filename=`[[!getVariable? &var=`report`]]`]]
```

but what I get back looks is just the page I am submitting the download request from back.

- the file does exist
- the correct file will download IF I place an exit(); after the download code.

I'm thinking this is happening because modx has already sent the headers?

How do I fix this?

Comment: And `file_exists($filename)` is very bad for security.

Answer (score 0):

Can you make `downloadReport` a separate file so you can use a clickable link? If not and you need time to build the csv you can always use the ajax+iframe trick, ie add a hidden iframe to the page and put your csvgenerator.php as the src.

Comment: I probably could send a clickable link in the success status message, but I'd much rather not from a UI standpoint ~ I would like them to click the form submit button, have the page refresh and just popup the file save dialogue.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to close modx session. Just add this code after `readfile`:

```
@session_write_close();
exit;
```

and

```
echo 'reading file';

ob_clean();
flush();
```

is unnecessary - remove it.

Comment: while using an exit will work, it also prevents me from doing anything else in the page. - can't clear the form [used to generate the report], can't send a success/fail message etc.

Comment: You can clear form by using javascript and send email in this snippet before exit - http://rtfm.modx.com/revolution/2.x/developing-in-modx/advanced-development/modx-services/modmail